# Windows Update error 80073701

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, service-pack

I know that this Windows Update error has been discussed on other questions, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/249641/error-80073701-when-installing-windows-7-service-pack-1) and Microsoft already has some good answers, like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-pt/kb/2700530) and [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/06/20/how-to-resolve-the-error-0x80073701-error-sxs-assembly-missing-when-you-are-installing-a-service-pack-or-hotfix.aspx). But no matter what I try (and I tried everything), I cannot install service pack 1 on my windows 7 machine. The windows update throw this error everytime I try.

Some details that could help to troubleshoot the issue:

OS Version - Windows 7 Home Premium x64 (original & activated) with all updates installed

SSD free space - 25 GB

Language : pt_PT

I tried to install manually too (downloading the service pack from microsoft's site) but no luck.
I'll post more details if needed.

Comment: You tried a Windows 7 repair? Did you review your CBS log to see what the exact issue is?

Comment: @Moab I cleaned up the log before running again the update process. The file have 1M+ lines... I don't see a specific issue in the file...

Comment: The do a repair install of W7.

Comment: @Moab I'm trying to avoid that at any cost..